# why is nginx not serving content when i redirect?

Tags: nginx

so, i got the webserver to redirect to my domain name when i type in the droplet ip address into the browser.  but it wont serve any of the content that was being served before i tried this.

how do i get it to both redirect to the domain.com AND show the content?

```
server {
        listen          80;
        listen          [::]:80;
        server_name     digital.ocean.ip.address;


        return 302 http://**mydomain**.com$request_uri;

}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;

        server_name http://**mydomain**.com;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  hm.html hm.htm;
    }

   error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

i should mention i am running nginx in a container 0.0.0.0:8081:80
(with port forwarding)

i've updated to this, because a single server block didn't work:

```
server {
        listen          80 default_server;
        listen          [::]:80;
        server_name     _;

return 301 domain.com$request_uri;

}

server {

        server_name domain.com;


    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  hm.html hm.htm;
    }
}
```

and now im gettin getting:

**414 Request-URI Too Large**

with the domain.com/domain.com/domain.com/ repeating

when i type [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) it takes me to the correct digital ocean ip address - so i believe dns is good.

so, i'm still unable to serve content, unless i dont redirect.  in which case if i type the ip address in, that's what shows on the browser.

Comment: Please give more debug information: What happens when you `curl` `localhost`, the IP address from the host, the ip address of the host, the domain, are there any messages in nginx error.log?

Comment: I think you should start with removing the protocol from the `server_name` and only put your `domain.com`. Then you probably also want to map port `80:80` or use `--network host`

Comment: @DanielW. the weirdest thing is happening...when i curl localhost and the droplet ip: i get the apache index.html that comes with the droplet.  before this i was getting the nginx welcome that i spun up.   also, im getting nothing on the domain

Comment: You get apache index because apache is already listening on port 80 of your server. Try `curl localhost:8081`. Stop apache and use port 80 for nginx if you dont want to provide the port number on each request.

Comment: @TheFool the reason i mapped it like this is because the ufw wasn't letting it get through on port 80 to a container

Comment: You also dont need 2 server blocks with a redirect. That is usually done when one listens on port 80 (HTTP) and the other on  port 443 (HTTPS).  You can also use `server_name _;`  and `listen 80 default_server` to let it match against all domain name, like a default server basically. Read me here : https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: Well you need to fix ufw, then. But It could just be that port 80 was already taken (by apache). Otherwise try `network_mode: host` in compose or `--network host` with docker run.

Comment: @TheFool this is really helpful.  i was able to kill apache and delete it.  now i get "Connection refused" which i guess is a good thing.  i also consolidated the server blocks - but still getting the same issue..i also tried listening on port 8081 but same thing(although not sure i have to since i have port forwarding..)

Comment: @TheFool to be clear..it was a combination of ufw not letting me into containers AND that im using podman not docker, which doesnt let rootless users use lower ports

Comment: But you forward like this `outside:inside` so when you have outside 8081 then thats where your actual server will be responsive to. So you really want `80:80`. Again if ufw is complaining use network mode host until you fixed ufw.

Comment: Ok but then this seems to be the main issue you need to work around, if you dont want to provide port 8081 on each request. Fix ufw and podman to let you have that port.

Comment: @TheFool just curious..because if i dont try to redirect to the domain...and just keep it at the ip...i get the content i want

Comment: @TheFool oh i see...is there a way to provide port 8081 on each request if i wanted?

Comment: sure like I have shown you with curl. Do `http://yourdomain.com:8081`

Comment: To your question why you get to the content if you only give the ip. As of current knowledge, I dont see a way it would be possible. There must be some other unknown factor. Or maybe you just looking at some cached response. Try it in a different browser once or clear your browser cache from network tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236101/discussion-between-the-fool-and-avnav88).